# SQL Hours how to order by start Hour

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a query returning data, qty and Hour.  it's a sum of all sales through the year.  I'm trying to achieve something like google busy times.  What I'm struggling with is ordering the hours.  I don't want 0-24, what I would like is 06-05.  So start time is 6 in the morning lets say and end time is 5 in the morning.  did something like  `Select Sum(Qty), Datepart(hh, saletime)`.  then grouped on sales.

Ordered this by saletime and get hours 0,1,2,3,4, etc.  but I wan the hours to start from 6 or other defined start hour.

Anyone help?

Comment: Please provide query

Comment: I added SQL Server, based on the code snippet.

Comment: `Order by case when Datepart(hh, saletime) >= @Var then Datepart(hh, saletime)-@var else Datepart(hh, saletime) 24-@VAR end`  passing in Var of 6 or whatever number.

Comment: Please use `hour` instead of lazy shorthand like `hh`. See [this post](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-dating-responsibly/).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is a little vague - could you edit your question to provide your query so far and your expected vs. actual output? For guidance please refer to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare your own sort order by doing a `CASE` statement which adds 24 hours to anything before 6.

Here, I've included it as a column so you can see what it's actually doing:

```
SELECT 
    Sum(Qty) as [Sum], 
    Datepart(hour, saletime) AS [Hour], 
    CASE 
        WHEN Datepart(hour, saletime) >= 6 THEN Datepart(hour, saletime)
        ELSE Datepart(hour, saletime) + 24 
    END AS [SortOrder]
FROM
    MyTable
ORDER BY
    SortOrder
```

**Output:**

```
Sum    Hour     SortOrder
2      6        6
3      7        7
17     8        8
--     --       --   Skipping rows for brevity
18     3        27
13     4        28
2      5        29
```

---

But if you don't want `SortOrder` as a column, just move it to the `ORDER BY` instead:

```
SELECT 
    Sum(Qty) as [Sum], 
    Datepart(hour, saletime) AS [Hour]
FROM
    MyTable
ORDER BY
    CASE 
        WHEN Datepart(hour, saletime) >= 6 THEN Datepart(hour, saletime) 
        ELSE Datepart(hour, saletime) + 24 
    END
```

---

**EDIT:** Per [Aaron Bertrand's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61305/aaron-bertrand) comment on the question itself, I've updated my queries to use `hour` instead of `hh`. The resource he provided can be [seen here](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-dating-responsibly/).

Comment: That was perfect thank you.  I wasn't even away you could use CASE in the order by.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a modula formula to sort:

```
select sum(qty), datepart(hour, saletime)
from sales
group by datepart(hour, saletime)
order by (datepart(hour, saletime) + 19) % 24
```